# Error "sort: cannot read: +1: no such file or directory"

Tags: shell-script

So I am working on a project for a UNIX class and we are following instructions from a book step by step. I recently got to a part where we are creating several functions inside a shell script but I can not get it to run properly even though my code is identical to what it says to do.

Some background:
 - source directory exists
 - the file corp_phones exists in that directory
 - I have loaded the function before attempting to use it

Here is my script:

```
sort_name()
 {
   sort +1 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
 }
sort_date()
 {
   sort +6 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
 }
sort_dept()
 {
   sort +4 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
 }
```

Comment: The books has the following steps:
1.Use the vi editor to create the .myfuncs file inside your source directory.
2.Enter the code(shown in question)
3. Save the file and exit the editor
4. At the command line, type . .myfuncs and press enter.
5. Test some functions. type sort_name and press enter.

Comment: We are running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: There are lessy lazy questions about the same subject.... https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9206/why-hidden-script-will-not-come-up/  ; the + is archaic  sort syntax.

Comment: Run `man sort`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the syntax you are using for sort is from an old version of POSIX. From the [coreutils manual for sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

> **On systems not conforming to POSIX 1003.1-2001, sort supports a
>   traditional origin-zero syntax ‘+pos1 [-pos2]’ for specifying sort
>   keys.** The traditional command ‘sort +a.x -b.y’ is equivalent to ‘sort
>   -k a+1.x+1,b’ if y is ‘0’ or absent, otherwise it is equivalent to ‘sort -k a+1.x+1,b+1.y’.
>
> This traditional behavior can be controlled with the _POSIX2_VERSION
>   environment variable (see Standards conformance); it can also be
>   enabled when POSIXLY_CORRECT is not set by using the traditional
>   syntax with ‘-pos2’ present.
>
> Scripts intended for use on standard hosts should avoid traditional
>   syntax and should use -k instead.

While it is possible to restore the traditional behaviour, it is more straightforward to use the newer syntax.

The `+1` option defines the sort key from the second field to the end of the line. The equivalent new option is `-k 2`. So the new `sort` commands you should use are, respectively:

```
sort -k 2 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
sort -k 7 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
sort -k 5 -t: ~/source/corp_phones
```

Comment: The inference from this answer is that the book text may be too old to be of much use.

Comment: @roaima Googling the filename 'corp_phones' pointed me towards a book called 'Guide to UNIX Using Linux'. The latest edition (fourth ed.) of that book seems okay - it has an identical question with the correct sort syntax. OP might be using the first edition, which was published back in 1999.

Comment: Yes.. that does rather sound like it might be. too old to be of great use